# Set Boolean value in hidden input

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that lets users send new product to database,
But I want to be able to review them before sending them,
So I want to set a Boolean input the the form so when User sends new product they wait in admin panel for review and after reviewing them admin can change the Boolean field and the product is published.

I made a hidden field in form and I want to give it the default value.
now no matter what I did, I cannot make the form to submit with the hidden boolean field value

forms.py :

```
class AccountProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountProduct
        fields = ('name','price','description','image','is_agahi')
        
        labels = {
            'name': '',
            'price': '',
            'description': '',
            'image': '',

        }
        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'image' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_agahi' : forms.HiddenInput(),
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._user = kwargs.pop('account_owner')
        super(AccountProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def save(self, commit=True):
        inst = super(AccountProductForm, self).save(commit=False)
        inst.account_owner = self._user
        if commit:
            inst.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return inst
```

views.py

```
def sell_account(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, account_owner=request.user)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Product Sent')
    else:
        form = AccountProductForm(account_owner=request.user)
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
            
    infos = AccountAgahiPage.objects.all().latest('id')
    return render(request, 'accountshop/account_sell.html',{'form':form, 'submitted':submitted, 'infos':infos})
```

models.py

```
...

    is_agahi = models.BooleanField(default=0, null=True)
```

I tried giving it Value = True with attrs in widgets dictionary in forms.py but didnt work